# what happens when the carry bit is zero in addition/subtraction algo for hardware

Tags: computers, register

[image: img]

This is the algorithm in flow diagram for addition and subtraction in computers.

*A(s)  is the sign bit of A*
*B(s) is the sign bit of B*

//(s) denotes the subscript

*E* is the register that has a carry  bit
*AVF* is the register that carries the overflow bit.
*A + As* is the accumulator register. *(A saver !)*
Initially the XOR operation is carried that checks if the sign bit of two numbers is same or not.

I understand this algorithm except the circled part. What is happening when E = 0  ? Please explain taking a simple example.

Comment: there should be an algorithm tag in _electronics.stackexchange.com_

Comment: That diagram looks more complicated than it ought to be. For subtraction you need just to complement B and consider the Borrow flag of subtraction be the complement of the Carry flag. Then you can just use addition.

Comment: @starblue: I agree; this looks unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @ davidcary @ starblue then can you please give a more modern flow chart

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is:

1. A is inverted.
2. A has 1 added to it.
3. A is inverted again.

This generates what is called the "Two's Complement" of the number in A.

Two's Complement is a way of encoding negative numbers in binary.

You can read more about Two's Complement here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: @ Majenko what is the need to encode here ? What do i get after encoding ?

Comment: Description "3." above is wrong. A is not inverted again, as the last line in the flow chart is inverting A(s) which is described as the sign bit for A, not inverting A proper.  Steps 1. and 2. alone do do a 2's complement, thus negating the numeric value in A.  A(s) seems to be a separate register.

Comment: I find it very hard to see the esses on the diagram, the size and quality is too low.

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of modern ALUs are "two's complement" adders, which don't need the "extra" steps you circled.

This looks like a [sign-and-magnitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Sign-and-magnitude_method) ALU, which I haven't seen in years.

Let's say we are subtracting (+7)-(+9).
In sign-and-magnitude format, we have

```
As = +; A = 0000_0111 (represents +7 in sign-and-magnitude notation)
Bs = +; B = 0000_1001 (represents +9 in sign-and-magnitude notation)
```

The first decision compares the signs.
Since +7 and +9 have the same sign (both positive), we go down the operations on the left:

```
EA <- A + !B + 1 = 0000_0111 + 1111_0110 + 1 = 0_1111_1110
```

so now

```
E = 0; A = 1111_1110
```

This is the two's complement representation of the result.
A two's complement ALU pretty much finishes here.
This flowchart illustrates a sign-and-magnitude ALU, which takes a few more steps:

Since that carry bit E is now 0, that implies that A was originally less than B, so we need to do a special fix-up to convert from two's complement notation to sign-and-magnitude notation:

```
A <- !A + 1 = !(1111_1110) + 1 = 0000_0001 + 1 = 0000_0010
As <- !As = !(+)
```

so we end up with

```
As = -; A = 0000_0010 (represents -2 in sign-and-magnitude notation)
```

Is that the correct result for (+7)-(+9) ?

Answer (score 0):

oh i explain!
actually u have to do a simple subtraction first
what is the value of 4-12
i.e -8
now come in binary equivalent of above decimal subtraction
4= 00100
12= 11000
-12= 2`s comp of 11000
i.e 00111+1=01000
now 4-12= 4+(-12)= 00100+01000= 01100
and 01100= 12 :O
but 4-12!=12!!!!!!!
actually if 0 is in 1st bit i.e in carry bit e=0
we have to make the 2`s comp of ans to got the actual answer
so 
2`s compliment of 01100= 10011+1= 10100
1st bit 1 denote that the answer commes was negative
and rest denote the answer
i.e
inn 10100
10100 means -ve 0100 i.e. -8
which is our real answer :)
hope you got